# Adding image to a message does not work when replying to a message

Tags: javascript, image, discord.js, message, imageurl

I am trying to get an image attached to a message which is a replay.

```js
msg.reply(JSON.parse(data).results[0].overview, { file : JSON.parse(data).results[0].poster_path});
```

but only the "overview" which is a string get sent, without the "poster_path" image.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

I have checked and the JSON data is valid.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post a sample payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code clearer and avoid memory overload, you can call this once

```js
   // get first value
   var firstResult = JSON.parse(data).results[0];

   // confirm the result
   console.log(firstResult);

   // action
   msg.reply(firstResult.overview, { file : firstResult.poster_path});
```

try view firstResult in the console to confirm the response.

Comment: I have taken the url printed to the console, pasted it in a search engien and it lead me to the desired picture

Comment: Okay, share the response, let me see how it looks like